# Keychain Item wrapper gives BAD_ACCESS_CODE=2

Tags: ios, keychainitemwrapper

I want to keep my app status in keychain. So I have to put like this

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItemLog = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"LoggedORNOT" accessGroup:nil];
[keychainItemLog setObject:@"STATUS" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
 keychainItemLog setObject:@"TOVERIFY" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

But in this line its getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS_Code=2` in following lines
- in my Viewcontroller-

```
[keychainItemLog setObject:@"STATUS" forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
```

-in KeychainItemWrapper.m -

```
NSAssert( result == noErr, @"Couldn't add the Keychain Item." );
```

and

```
 [self writeToKeychain];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are confusing between `setObject` and `setValue`, change your setting as below:

```
[keychainItemLog setObject:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData) forKey:@"STATUS"];
```

Comment: Not sure I got your question but you just need to switch between the value and the key, @"STATUS" supposed to be the key, and `kSecValueData` is the value.

Comment: If the key is `NSString` then it works, but you need to understand that you will get the value by the key you gave, I suggest to double check the other places ;).